# How do I parse constructor parameter to ViewModel using empty codebehind file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

My views constructor has this parameter IDatabase _db but I want my ViewModel to get this, but I am creating my VM this way

`xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:OppStd.ViewModel"`

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

To get a empty code behind file, now I am just in doubt how to route this parameter to my viewmodel using XAML

So is it possible to parse this construtor? Also I am using MVVM Light if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view model should not need to know about the view.
The view shouldn't need to know about a database either.

Why does your view's constructor take the parameter `IDatabase _db`? Most likely you should change this.

Comment: I will make a static property that returns a reference to the database instead that the viewmodel can call

Comment: Yes, that would work and be compatible with the MVVM pattern you are using. However you may want to pass the database reference to the view model in its constructor (that is called dependency injection), or use a service locator (which another way to achieve inversion of control). I prefer the former, but the latter seems to be all the rage these days, and probably fits in well with the way MVVM Light does things.

Comment: It is Ok to use injection in VMs, though typically I use abstracted services to do this (for example IDataService, which does not inform the VM about how exactly the data is resolved). However, as you found out, you cannot use injection (or any parameter) if the VM is created in XAML (XAML being a serialization language needs the default constructor). As Kent mentioned, using the ViewModelLocator helps for this. See my videos at http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/EX14 and http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03 for details.

Comment: I also prefer dependency injection. Check the videos I mention in the previous comment, you will see techniques used in MVVM Light to achieve this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVVM Light, you should be using the ViewModelLocator to resolve the view model. Tutorials such as [this one](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/04/wpfs-mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-part-i/) explain in greater detail.